# Group by element in array by keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am developing an application on AngularJS (1) and I can not figure out how to split array of items in another array group by item.

I mean I have an array of different items and I would group items by uuid like:

```
[
    {"name": "toto", "uuid": 1111},
    {"name": "tata", "uuid": 2222},
    {"name": "titi", "uuid": 1111}
];
```

Is going to be:

```
[
    [
        {"name": "toto", "uuid": 1111},
        {"name": "titi", "uuid": 1111}
    ],
    [
        {"name": "tata", "uuid": 2222}
    ]
];
```

I have tried loop and loop again on forEach function but it's very long if my array is long

Comment: *I have tried..* - Why don't you show us the code you tried ?

Comment: inutile @Weedoze

Comment: You are not showing any effort thus not showing what you tried is not **inutile**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table and collect the object in the arrays of the hash table.

```js
var array = [{ name: "toto", uuid: 1111 }, { name: "tata", uuid: 2222 }, { name: "titi", uuid: 1111 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!hash[a.uuid]) {
        hash[a.uuid] = [];
        result.push(hash[a.uuid]);
    }
    hash[a.uuid].push(a);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `Object.values()`

```js
let a = [
    {"name": "toto", "uuid": 1111},
    {"name": "tata", "uuid": 2222},
    {"name": "titi", "uuid": 1111}
];

let b = Object.values(a.reduce((a,b) => {
    a[b.uuid] = a[b.uuid] ? a[b.uuid].concat(b) : [b];
    return a;
}, {}));

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use an established library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to make it a lot simpler and save yourself the trouble:

```js
let arr = [
    {"name": "toto", "uuid": 1111},
    {"name": "tata", "uuid": 2222},
    {"name": "titi", "uuid": 1111}
]

let grouped = _.groupBy(arr, 'uuid')

console.log(grouped)
console.log(Object.values(grouped))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```